# login after reload page wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using the litespeed cache plugin. page does not refresh when users log in.

**page refresh code I use**

```
                    if ("reload" == response.data.action) {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    }
```

but not working.

this code does not refresh the page. I think it's about litespeed cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a **query string** when you are enqueueing your javascript file. something like this,

```
my-script.js?ver=21524
```

Then on the **WordPress Dashboard**, navigate to go to **Litespeed Cache > Settings > Cache** and scroll down to the Drop Query String setting.

In this box, you can list the strings you want to ignore, one per line

```
21524
425358
```

Save Changes button, and you’re done.